# how to select the first number in a link

Tags: php, regex

I have a link, something like this:

```
$link = 'http://www.example/data/showall.php?quantity=&lang=eng&sura=2&ayat=21';
```

Now I want the first number of it, In this case I want `2`.

Note: All characters are fixed except the numbers.

To simplify my string, I can replace the first of it with empty, something like this:

```
$link ='2&ayat=21';
```

Now I want `2`.

I can do that by regex: `/\d+/`.  But I don't want to remove it, I want it,
how can I do this ?

Comment: why not use $_GET['sura'] or substr($_GET['sura'], 0, 1) ?

Comment: @Baron I have not a form and POST/GET data, I have a like as a string.

Comment: oh, try $first_num = substr(preg_replace('/\D/', '', $link), 0, 1); now you have new variable ($first_num).

Comment: @Baron your solution is great. thanks! **EDIT:** It working just for single-digit numbers. Try to fix it and create a answer for my question. I will give you +voteup ;)

Comment: Try $parse = parse_url($link); parse_str($parse['query'], $get); echo $get['sura']; now you have new array ($get), in your problem, you just need $get['sura']

Comment: @Baron worked correctly. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this to get capture first digit:

```
[^0-9]*(\d+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rN4jN8/1)

`PHP Code:`

```
<?php

$link = 'http://www.example/data/showall.php?quantity=&lang=eng&sura=2&ayat=21';
preg_match('/[^0-9]*(\d+)/',$link,$matches);
echo $matches[1];

?>
```

`Output:`

```
2
```

Comment: Thanks buddy ..! But did not work ! I want to my output be `2`

Comment: @stack , I've tested it, I also added php code and output in the answer, see it

Comment: i think `echo $matches[1];` should be `echo $matches[0];`

Comment: @Viral , `$matches[0]` has the whole string that regex matches, `$matches[1]` contains string captured by first capturing parenthesis

Comment: Worked correctly. Thank, just edit your answer and add a plus `+` after `\d`, Because the first number is not always a digit.

Comment: @stack , yeah but i thought u wanted a single digit, edited answer anyway :)

Comment: Just for more information, Is it possible to echo second number ?! Thanks

Comment: @stack , yes change `preg_match` to `preg_match_all` and `$matches` will grab em all and store in array use `print_r($matches)` and extract what u need from it , `21` will be stored in `$matches[0][1]` and `2` in `$matches[0][0]`

Comment: I see, just edit your comment and replace `$matches[1][0]; //2` instead `$matches[0][1]` and then `$matches[1][1]; //21` instead of `$matches[0][0]`. good luck Bro.

Comment: @stack , yeah `[0]` in case of whole regex match :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not want to use REGEX,

```
$url = 'http://www.example/data/showall.php?quantity=&lang=eng&sura=2&ayat=21';

parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $array );

$first = array_filter($array, function($v){
    return is_numeric($v);
});

var_dump(array_values($first)[0]);
```

Comment: I checked it. It does not even run.

Comment: Still it does not work. But +upvote for your idea. *(parse_url)*

Answer (score 0):

Full code from my comment

```
$link = 'http://www.example/data/showall.php?quantity=&lang=eng&sura=2&ayat=21';
$parse = parse_url($link);
parse_str($parse['query'], $get);
echo $get['sura']; // or var_dump($get);

/* output $get['sura'] = 2
   output $get['ayat'] = 21 */
```